# Problem: Why does cv2.VideoWriter() does not compile the frames read completely?

Tags: python, opencv, video-processing, yolov5

I encountered this problem when using `detect.py` from Ultralytics (YOLOv5). My input video that is 2 minutes and 37 seconds long became produces a video with bounding boxes that is only 1 minute and 19 seconds long.

I currently narrowed down the problem down to `cv2.VideoWriter()` when I tried to read the frames of my input video using the usual `cap.read()` in an infinite while loop and then reconstruct the frames back to a single `.mp4` file (using `cv2.VideoWriter()`) wherein the same thing happened (the output video duration decreased).

Upon observation, the output video stopped somewhere in the middle. Although it was still playing from the `cap.read()` and `cv2.imshow()`, the `cv2.VideoWriter()` seemed to stop compiling the frames beyond 1 minute and 19 seconds (not sure but this is a guess regarding why it happened).

This is the question that I raised in the repository of Ultralytics' YOLOv5: https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5/issues/12372

Kindly view it and scroll down in the comments' section for more details regarding my input video.

Any responses/insights will be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: [mre] required. the reported frame rate of a video file may just be guesswork. opencv cannot handle writing a video with a "presentation timestamp" per frame. use PyAV.

Comment: Please click [edit] and add your [mcve]. At the moment, your question says you ran some code we can't see on a video we don't have and you did or didn't get some errors and the result was shorter. Thank you.